# Routes React no funciona en Netlify

Tags: reactjs

tengo un problema, no me funciona routes en react cuando lo pruebo en netlify, pero lo pongo en codesandbox y en la vista previa si funciona, tengo estos archivos:

`App.js`

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "./ruta/Home";
import Second from "./ruta/Dos";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/dos" element={<Second />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`ruta/Home`

```
function Home() {
  return <p>The Home</p>;
}

export default Home;
```

`ruta/Dos`

```
function Second() {
  return <p>Not the Home</p>;
}

export default Second;
```

`index.js`

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  rootElement
);
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "React example starter project",
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "starter"
  ],
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "6.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "7.13.8",
    "typescript": "3.2.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba con crear el archivo `_redirects` dentro del directorio `public` con el contenido de `/*  /index.html  200` de esa manera, cualquier URL será redireccionada al index.html

Comment: te amo, eso funcionó perfecto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aun que la pregunta esta resuelta, dejo la respuesta por si en un futuro alguien se encuentra con el mismo problema.

Al crear una web SPA, tenemos que decirle al servidor, que las rutas las vamos a controlar desde la parte del cliente, para eso, tenemos que decirle que cualquier ruta sea redireccionada a nuestro punto de entrada, que suele ser un `index.html`(en caso de react).

Y esto pasa exactamente con netlify, y la manera de configurarlo es crear un archivo llamado `_redirects` dentro del directorio `public` con el contenido

```
/*  /index.html  200
```

De esta manera al acceder a cualquier ruta, el servidor enviara el archivo de entrada y este mismo ya tomara el control de inicializar/crear y controlar el resto de la aplicación.